# Add a second signature in iPhone/iPad Mail

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, email

I have 2 email accounts on my iPhone and iPad, a work and personal.

I have edited a signature for my work account but can only seem to have one signature.

I also use Mail.app on OSX which lets me change between accounts that automaticly reply/send with the correct signature.

The iOS app doesn't seem to match a signature to an account rather it looks as though it attaches the signature to the iPhone.

Is there a way to add another signature to Mail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS only supports a single signature, but you can use iOS 5's new text Shortcut feature to manage multiple signatures. The feature is in the Settings app under "General | Keyboard | Shortcuts".

Add a shortcut for each signature, e.g. wsig = Work Signature and psig = Personal Signature

Shortcut only supports single lines of text, so I get around this by having my default sig be my name plus a new line, then I type the shortcut text on the blank line after my name.

Comment: Sadly correct, and a good work around, however my signature is a few lines and also has some formatting in it. I will just delete from my email when using personal signature.

Comment: Take a look at TextExpander touch from Smile software. It's like Shortcut on steroids (also, not free).I don't use it, and I'm not sure how convenient it is, workflow-wise, but I know LOTS of people use it and like it.